# Sending message to specific channel, not working

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Having trouble sending a bot message on a specific channel. I very simply want to have the bot send a message to #general when it activates, to let everyone know it's working again.

In the bot.on function, I've tried the classic client.channels.get().send(), but the error messages I'm getting show that it thinks client is undefined. (It says "cannot read property 'channels' of undefined")

```
bot.on('ready', client => {
    console.log("MACsim online")
    client.channels.get('#general').send("@here");
})
```

The bot crashes immediately, saying: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the guild / server by ID, and then the channel by ID, so your code will be something like :

```js
const discordjs = require("discord.js");
const client = new discordjs.Client();

bot.on('ready', client => {
console.log("MACsim online")
    client.guilds.get("1836402401348").channels.get('199993777289').send("@here");
})
```

Edit : added client call

Comment: @NeonEviscerator How do you call your discord client?

Comment: Thanks, this did fix my issue, I forgot that I assigned the Doscord clint to 'bot' not 'client'. I changed all client calls to bot and the issue is now fixed, thanks for the help.

Comment: @NeonEviscerator Np, could you check my answer as "accepted" answer?

Comment: Yep, sorry for not doing that earlier. I'm new to SO and didn't realize it was something you were supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

The `ready` event doesn't pass any `client` parameter.
To get a channel by name use `collection.find()`:

```
client.channels.find(channel => channel.name == "channel name here");
```

To get a channel by ID you can simply do `collection.get("ID")` because the channels are mapped by their IDs.

```
client.channels.get("channel_id");
```

Here is an example I made for you:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Client = new Discord.Client();

Client.on("ready", () => {
   let Channel = Client.channels.find(channel => channel.name == "my_channel");
   Channel.send("The bot is ready!");
});

Client.login("TOKEN");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ready` event does not pass a parameter. To gain the bot's client, simply use the variable that you assigned when you created the client.
From your code, it looks like the `bot` variable, where you did `const bot = new Discord.Client();`.
From there, using the `bot` (which is the bot's client), you can access the `channels` property!