# make discord bot to send message specific channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I wanna make bot command like this:

I write in a chat: `~msg (Text) (Channel)`, then the bot will send a message such as: `Hello everyone. (In channel General)`.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```js
switch (args[0]) {
 case 'msg':

if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send('Fill the channel name')
            if (!args[2]) return message.channel.send('Fill the text')
            message.client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === args[1]).send(args[2]);

    }
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending message to specific channel, not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58144077/sending-message-to-specific-channel-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.find()` method to get a channel by name and then simply send a message there with the `.send()` method.

```js
message.client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === chanArgs).send(msgArgs)
```

Comment: `message.client`??

Comment: Any `client` object will do. For example, if you wrote `const client = new Discord.Client()`, then you could just use `client.channels...`

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined,i think this almost correct

Comment: That just means it couldn't find a channel by the name provided. Make sure `chanArgs` is a valid channel name.

Comment: thanks it works, but when I type the 3rd argument onwards it doesn't show up. do you have a solution? so you can write so on.i just edit the code u can check it @Lioness100

Comment: `const text = args.slice(2).join(" ")`

Comment: (You can replace `text` with `msgArgs` I was just using it as a placeholder name)